# Python: condition to check that none of list's element is an empty list

Tags: python, list, if-statement, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have a list of list`A`; each element of A is a list.
I want a condition (to use for a if statement) that return `True` if all the element of `A` are non empty and `False` otherwise.
How can I express this condition?

Example 1

```py
A = [[], [5]]
if (condition):
    print("no empty list as elements of A")
else:
    print("at least an empty list inside A")
```

```
>>> at least an empty list inside A
```

Example 2

```py
A = [[3,2], [5]]
if (condition):
    print("no empty list as elements of A")
else:
    print("at least an empty list inside A")
```

```
>>> no empty list as elements of A
```

I tried with the condition

```py
if(not b for b in A):
```

but it seems not to work properly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since an non-empty list is considered truthy, you can use `all`:

```
if all(A):
    print("No empty list in A")
else:
    print("At least one empty list in A")
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I was looking for! Do you know why the solution that I tried (end of the question) doesn't work?

Comment: `(not b for b in A)` is a generator expression, which is always true. You aren't actually iterating over it, and if you did, you'd have a list of boolean values, not a single one.